# Flink WordCount.jar sample file not running on local kubernetes

Tags: jar, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I have started a local k8s deployment of flink by using their helm chart on my minikube cluster

`helm install -n flink riskfocus/flink --generate-name`

After that, on my PC I opened `localhost:8081/` and I do see the UI as it should, with 4 available task slots and 0 jobs

Then, on that same UI I click on `Submit new Job` and upload the WordCount.jar file that comes from $FLINK_HOME/examples/batch when you download & uncompress flink https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/flink/flink-1.17.1/flink-1.17.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz

So after I uplaoded the .jar file, to start the job, on the UI I set level of parallelism to 1, and no parameters nor savePoint. I believe there should be no issue since I presume from this repo is where the source code of the WordCount.jar is coming from, and it says that there's no need for input_path nor output_path as it would just take a hardcoded text as input and output it on console https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java

However what I get after clicking `Submit` is this error:

```
Server Response:org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application. at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(JarRunHandler.java:103) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1609) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Could not execute application. at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1606) ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Could not execute application. at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:81) at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:67) at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:100) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Job was submitted in detached mode. Results of job execution, such as accumulators, runtime, etc. are not available. Please make sure your program doesn't call an eager execution function [collect, print, printToErr, count]. at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:302) at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198) at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149) at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:78) ... 10 more Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Job was submitted in detached mode. Results of job execution, such as accumulators, runtime, etc. are not available. Please make sure your program doesn't call an eager execution function [collect, print, printToErr, count]. at org.apache.flink.core.execution.DetachedJobExecutionResult.getAccumulatorResult(DetachedJobExecutionResult.java:54) at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:415) at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1652) at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:288) ... 13 more
```

Also, as a second request. How do I run pyflink .py files? I have .py files but the UI only takes .jar files. And I am on a windows machine so the flink CLI doesn't works, what I mean is I can't use this `flink run --python <path_to.py>`